# Execution time of a MARS MIPS program

Tags: mips, execution-time

I know the execution time of a program = Instruction count x CPI x Clock cycles, but i don't know the CPI of each instruction in mars mips. Therefore, how to determine the CPI of each instruction or each type of instruction in mars mips.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You'd have to look at a user's manual, it's the only way to know for sure.